# Named function and anonymous function having different effects

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, refactoring, closures, anonymous-function

**My problem:**

I'm refactoring some of my code, and giving names to some long anonymous function. Unfortunately, it breaks the app in ways I don't understand.

**The code**

Anonymous version works fine,

> alert(distributeurs.length);

is different from 0.

```
 var group = this.settings.group, //group used to store all the markers added to the map
            leads = this.model.get("leads"), // collection of leads
            distributeurs = new Distributeurs(), // collection of distributeurs
            map = this.settings.map,
            addLeadsCollection = this.addLeadsCollectionFnContructor();


        //ajax calls to populate collection
        $.when(leads.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) }), distributeurs.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) })).done(
            function () //the function
            {
                alert( distributeurs.length ); //the alert
                distributeurs.map( function ( distributeur )
                {
                    addLeadsCollection( leads.filter( function ( lead )
                    {
                        return distributeur.get( "id" ) === lead.get( "distribution" );
                    }
                ) );
                }
            );
            }
        );
```

Named version: it does nothing as

> alert(distributeurs.length);

is always valued at 0.

```
var group = this.settings.group, //group used to store all the markers added to the map
            leads = this.model.get("leads"), // collection of leads
            distributeurs = new Distributeurs(), // collection of distributeurs
            map = this.settings.map,
            addLeadsCollection = this.addLeadsCollectionFnContructor();



        //the function
        var addCollections = function() {
            alert(distributeurs.length); //the alert
            distributeurs.map(function(distributeur) {
                addLeadsCollection(leads.filter(function(lead) {
                    return distributeur.get("id") === lead.get("distribution");
                }
                ));
            }
            );
        };

        //ajax calls to populate collection
        $.when(leads.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) }), distributeurs.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) })).done(
            addCollections()
        );
```

**My question**

Why do those two functions behave differently, and how should I declare my named function to make it act like the anonymous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parentheses from `addCollections()`. You're calling the function immediately; what you want to do is pass the function instead.

Actually your function is anonymous in both cases. All you've done in the second case is assign a reference to the function to a variable. To make the function not anonymous, you can use a *function declaration*:

```
function addCollections() {
    // Stuff...
}
```

... or use a [*named function expression*](http://kangax.github.io/nfe/):

```
var addCollections = function someName() {
    // someName is now a reference to the function, but only
    // within the function
};
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not a named function, you are assigning a function to a variable called `addCollections`. Your problem is that you are calling the function instead of passing in the reference here:

```
$.when(leads.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) }), distributeurs.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) })).done(
            addCollections()
        );
```

remove the parentheses:

```
$.when(leads.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) }), distributeurs.fetch({ data: $.param({ departementCode: departementCode }) })).done(
                addCollections
            );
```